# Handling termination in Fast CGI on Windows IIS servers

Tags: fastcgi

Finding windows FastCGI help is proving very difficult. 
Any help would be greatly apprciated.

The concept of FastCGi is that the process survives a request allowing you to maintain state between calls. This means you do not have the overhead of opening databases etc between calls.

Apart from that, FastCGI is fully multiplexed:
http://cryp.to/publications/fastcgi/#MULTIPLEXING

The problem lies in the C API

The source for libfcgi.dll is available here:
http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/5

This is not supported by MS as anyone connected with FCGI or IIS points out in a hurry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new windows FastCGI library was needed to implement the FastCGI SIGTERM handler
www.coastrd.com